# phpmyadmin insert statement syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

The values aren't getting inserted into the table. I tried both ways,one is directly inserting data,the other one is by passing the saved variable value and yet it isn't getting inserted. Could some one help?

The structure of the table is

```
CREATE TABLE store
    (`storeid` int, `storename` varchar(20), `starttime` int,`stoptime` int, `address` varchar(20), `contact` varchar(20));


<?php include 'database.php'; ?>

<?php
echo "hello";
$id= $_POST['t1'];
$name=$_POST['t2'];
$stime=$_POST['t3'];
$sttime=$_POST['t4'];
$add=$_POST['area'];
$con=$_POST['no'];
echo 'end';

mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO store(t1,t2,t3,t4,area,no) VALUES (' 1 ',' hai ',' 9 ',' 10 ',' asa ',' 29148 ')");


mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO store(t1,t2,t3,t4,area,no) VALUES (' $id ',' $name ',' $stime ',' $sttime ',' $add ',' $con ')");    


    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0){
echo 'no';
    echo "<p>Employee Added</p>";

}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: check for Errors after executing SQL Statement (use mysqli_error()). echo out the query and try it in a database console

Comment: where is your connection defined. the variable `$connect` which you are using

Comment: the $connect statement is defined in database.php which is included in the first statement. Had added it initially,but didn't show up in the code above. Indented it properly,now its visible. The database is getting connected.

Comment: @Jens Yes will try that. Thankyou

Comment: Is there no record in your table or are all fields empty?

Comment: There is one record that i inserted directly in the phpmyadmin. Now I am trying to insert it through the code above.

Comment: Also, if you do in fact have enumerated column names then you can be sure that your design is flawed

Comment: So what's your table structure look like? could you please create a sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: add you structure of MySQL Table in the Question.

Comment: Structure has been added.

Comment: @Strawberry Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Where are the columns: `t1,t2,t3,t4,area,no` in your create table statement?

Comment: @jens Its retrieved from html page. The form action of the html page is this php field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Formular fields as column names. That won't work. you have to use the column names:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO store(storeid,storename,starttime,stoptime,address,contact) VALUES VALUES ('$id','$name','$stime','$sttime','$add','$con')");
```

And as i wrote in my comment: Use prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection.

Also you should check for Errors after executing SQL Statements (mysqli_error()). If you do it, you see the error message and it is easier to evaluate it.

Comment: could you elaborate about the formular fields? i used those t1,t2 etc based on how it was given in https://www.eduonix.com/blog/web-programming-tutorials/learn-submit-html-data-mysql-database-using-php/ website.

Comment: regarding the sql injection and errors.. yes i am trying it out.

Comment: @Swathi Formular fields are the names you used in your HTML to identify the Input fileds

Comment: Yes t1,t2,t3..etc are the names which I used to identify the input fields. And I used the same. Doesn't it work? I had just referred that website I mentioned in the previous comment and wrote it accordingly.

Comment: @Swathi Your HTML and your database are two different things. You get the values of the form fields in the lines $_POST['t1']; and so on. After that the names are not longer intersting for you. For inserting into the database you have to use the column names in the first part of the SQL statement

Comment: Oh okay. Go it now. Used your query,not working yet. I guess there is problem with my syntax itself, coz even without variables,if I pass the values just as such also it isn't getting inserted.  Checking with the errors after its execution now.

Comment: @Swathi if you have any error message, feel free to come back and we can evaluate this

Comment: Yes sir. Searching for syntax of assigning the query statement to a variable as it is a Object of class mysqli_result.

Comment: It worked finally. I had inserted a row already through mysqladmin. Now after I executed your query the primary key condition was being violated.Checked it through the error condition.Thankyou so much. Grateful to you.

Answer (score -1):

If the connect variable is correct and getting proper connection,
try doing this code:

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `store` (t1,t2,t3,t4,area,no) VALUES ('1','hai','9','10','asa','29148')");
```

or

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `store` (t1,t2,t3,t4,area,no) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$stime."','".$sttime."','".$add."','".$con."')");
```

here should be no spaces in the values.

More about this : 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-php-and-mysql/php-insert-database

The second one also describes better checking of variables before inserting it into db.

Comment: Yes it is getting connected properly. I tried using your code. But still it isn't working.

Comment: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-php-and-mysql/php-insert-database. I had tried using the syntax mentioned in this website too. Even that isn't working.

Comment: Didn't get which one it is sir.

Comment: instead of store use `store` and in passing variables see how it is passed now. For more you can refer to the above mentioned link where they have given the answer.

Comment: Oh okay. Yea got it now.

Comment: My mistake was in using t1,t2,t3... etc which was to be replaced by the column names in the first part of the SQL statement.